# Change href based on class

Tags: javascript, class, href

how to add a prefix before a link only to a certain category of class.

```
<p class="syndicated-attribution">
    <a href="http://www.example.com/">Read more →</a>
</p>
```

using js like that

```
$('.syndicated-attribution a').attr('href', function() {
    return 'http://site.com/' + $(this).text()
});
```

Eg: http://www.example.com --> http://site.com/http://www.example.com

is very simple, as I do?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this).text()` Is the content within the tag:

```
<a href="site.com">THIS IS THE TEXT</a>
```

You don't want the text. You want the `href`. You're already using the `attr('href')` function, so...

Comment: Yes! $('.class li a').attr('href', function() {
    return 'http://adf.ly/banner/' + $(this).attr('href')
});

Comment: you can change the url when you click? therefore, if you hover the link not appear the url changed?!

Comment: If you have another question, [ask it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), don't use the comments for unrelated questions.